# How do I add categories to google action trivia game (template)?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I am following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/actions/templates/trivia) to create a trivia game for my Google Home mini. How do I edit the default excel template to assign categories to the questions? The page says that the game can support up to 9 categories, but I'm not sure how to implement this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After you copy the google sheet and create your own, you can scroll to column G (title: Category/Topic) and add there the categories for each question.

One of the things to remember is that you wish to have few questions per each category and for each 'Difficulty/Grade Level' so the game will be interesting and the user will get different questions each time. 
Here is a working example that I've created '[Runner Trivia Game](https://greenido.wordpress.com/2017/10/09/a-new-google-assistant-app-runner-trivia-game/)' - I did use only 2 categories (for now) as I wanted at least 12 questions per category.

Good luck!

Comment: I changed G7 to "Category/Topic" and added a specific category for each question (there are a total of 4 possible categories). I changed F7 to "Difficulty/Grade Level" and set them all to "Easy" for now. When I upload this new sheet to my trivia game, it says 24 rows detected but when I test, the assistant says "not enough questions." Any thoughts on why this is happening? Do you happen to have a read-only link to the sheet for your game?

Comment: Here is another example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eoMS2K5Rmf2RXZGIyyNymYTAsg5v9aJtpJGGfGcgixY/edit?usp=sharing
Make sure that you have enough questions for every possible category/difficulty combination.